# Trouble Installing AMD r9 380 GPU Pro driver in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: amd-graphics

I am trying to install the AMDGPU Pro driver in Ubuntu 16.10. When i try to start the install script i get /etc/os-release: line 3: OS: command not found. I have tried several ways to get the driver to install ,it just will not do it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, AMDGPU-Pro drivers only support Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit (kernel Linux 4.4): http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx

If you need this "hybrid" driver, you have to install Xenial instead of Yakkety